# Проблема со сравнением char. C++

Tags: c++, linux, кодировка, char

При вводе строки "ff" код ниже выдаёт "Равны". При вводе строки "аа" - "Не равны".

```
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;


int main() {

std::string s;
cin >> s;
if (s[0]==s[1]) {
    cout << "Равны";
} else {
    cout << "Не равны";
}


return 0;
}
```

Я думаю, что проблема в кодировках, однако находил решения только под windows.

Код компилируется с помощью gcc. Стандарт C++17. Система - ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Просто русские буквы в utf-8 занимают больше 1 символа, так что вы сравниваете составные части одной буквы `а`...

Comment: @Harry А как мне тогда правильно их сравнить?

Comment: хочется сравнивать два символа?

Comment: @KoVadim изначально хочется проверить является ли каждый символ в строке русской или английской буквой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конвертируем *простую* строку с кодировкой UTF-8 в "широкую" строку и сравниваем **буквы** (а не коды).

```
# include <locale>
# include <codecvt>

std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
std::wstring ws = converter.from_bytes(s);

if (ws[0]==ws[1]) {
```

Comment: `Конверитруем в строку с кодировкой UTF-8` Что? стоп стоп.... В линуксе по умолчанию utf-8...

Comment: Я подправил .. @こきん

Comment: надо оговориться, что, во-первых, `codecvt_utf8_utf16` задеприкатили в c++17, а, во-вторых, это будет некорректно работать с символами юникода из дополнительных плоскостей, которые в utf-16 представляются несколькими символами...

Comment: Согласен, ... но пока работает хоть такое с русскими буквами. @Fat-Zer

Answer (score 1):

Так как ff это часть ascii таблицы, то один символ оттуда представляется в виде одного байта, а русские буквы в этом случае относятся к символам, имеющим двубайтовую кодировку. В си для таких случаев используется wchar_t, а wstring - это контейнер соответственно. Поэтому в обычном string в случае с русскими буквами ты сравниваешь первый и второй байт буквы а.